# Splitting two dates from one column into two different columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a column which contains two Date which is Start Date and End Date

```
+---------------StartAndEndDate--------------+
+      JayZ -  (08/21/2016 - 08/22/2016)     +
+--------------------------------------------+
```

Based on previous example, above is only one column. How can I split given date and store it in two different column.

Expected output should be

```
+----StartDate----+----EndDate----+
+   08/21/2016    +  08/22/2016   +
+-----------------+---------------+
```

Just FYI: Character before ( is random length can change. For Instance

```
+---------------StartAndEndDate--------------+
+   JayZ -  (08/21/2016 - 08/22/2016)        +
+   JohnSmith -  (09/11/2016 - 09/20/2016)   +
+   Rick from NY -  (08/21/2016 - 08/22/2016)+
+--------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I don't have any idea how to do this

Comment: We want to at least see your attempt.  We can correct your code if it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to look at CHARINDEX and SUBSTRING. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx

Comment: Can't use CHARINDEX as data before ( is not fixed length. Also Cannot use SUBSTRING as Starting and ending position is not fix.

Comment: *Why* do you store all that information in a single field? That's a very serious design problem. This can't be fixed easily with SQL, because SQL isn't meant for parsing, especially complex parsing like this.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that was not created by me. Was created by my client.

Comment: Both of the answers helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the name part can change length you can still use [CHARINDEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) and [SUBSTRING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #Source 
(
    StartAndEndDate nvarchar(1000)
);

INSERT INTO #Source (StartAndEndDate)
VALUES
    ('JayZ -  (08/21/2016 - 08/22/2016)'),
    ('JohnSmith -  (09/11/2016 - 09/20/2016)'),
    ('Rick from NY -  (08/21/2016 - 08/22/2016)');

SELECT
    *
FROM
    #Source;

SELECT
    SUBSTRING(StartAndEndDate, CHARINDEX('-', StartAndEndDate) + 4, 10) as StartDate,
    SUBSTRING(StartAndEndDate, CHARINDEX('-', StartAndEndDate) + 17, 10) as EndDate
INTO 
    #Destination
FROM
    #Source

SELECT
    *
FROM
    #Destination;

DROP TABLE #Source;
DROP TABLE #Destination;
```

The only caveat to this is that the name can't include a hyphen. Another approach is to count from the end of the string like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #Source 
(
    StartAndEndDate nvarchar(1000)
);

INSERT INTO #Source (StartAndEndDate)
VALUES
    ('JayZ -  (08/21/2016 - 08/22/2016)'),
    ('JohnSmith -  (09/11/2016 - 09/20/2016)'),
    ('Rick from NY -  (08/21/2016 - 08/22/2016)');

SELECT
    *
FROM
    #Source;

SELECT
    SUBSTRING(StartAndEndDate, LEN(StartAndEndDate) - 23, 10) as StartDate,
    SUBSTRING(StartAndEndDate, LEN(StartAndEndDate) - 10, 10) as EndDate
INTO 
    #Destination
FROM
    #Source

SELECT
    *
FROM
    #Destination;

DROP TABLE #Source;
DROP TABLE #Destination;
```

**Performance**

Following some comments about performance, I ran a **very crude** performance test on my extremely quite database. Splitting the field on 100,000 rows is taking 30 to 50 ms. Basically it is fast enough that I'm worrying about the resolution [SYSDATETIME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630353.aspx)() can manage. On a busier database things are likely to be slower, but it is the reads, writes and indexes that will be the issue not the string split. Code I used is as follows:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

CREATE TABLE #Source 
(
    StartAndEndDate nvarchar(1000)
);

DECLARE 
    @i int = 100000,
    @l int = 0;

WHILE (@i > 0)
BEGIN
    SET @l = RAND() * 20;

    INSERT INTO #Source (StartAndEndDate)
    VALUES
        (SUBSTRING('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 0, @l) + ' -  (08/21/2016 - 08/22/2016)' );

    SET @i = @i - 1;
END

SELECT
    *
FROM
    #Source;

DECLARE @Start DateTime = SYSDATETIME();

SELECT
    SUBSTRING(StartAndEndDate, LEN(StartAndEndDate) - 23, 10) as StartDate,
    SUBSTRING(StartAndEndDate, LEN(StartAndEndDate) - 10, 10) as EndDate
INTO 
    #Destination
FROM
    #Source

PRINT 'Time Taken ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(50), DATEDIFF(ms, @Start, SYSDATETIME())) + 'ms';    

SELECT
    *
FROM
    #Destination;

DROP TABLE #Source;
DROP TABLE #Destination;
```

Comment: Those three are just example but infact there are 100,000 records will you do this way for those records?

Comment: Yes, how often do you run this?

Comment: whenever new data is inserted. And it is inserted in bulk.

Comment: Are we talking every three milliseconds or once a day?

Comment: I'd like to know *why* the field breaks 1NF when there are 100K records. There should be 3 different fields. The practical solution would be to fix the schema then run an ETL script to transfer the data. The only workaround with acceptable performance is a SQLCLR method that performs this complex parsing. Using T-SQL for this will hurt *a lot*

Comment: Or a regex expression in an SSIS flow that is used to perform the bulk insert operation

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I would love to do via SSIS. But I had requirement do to via Select statement.  But I think it is better to approch via second sample query which Martin provided. Which is `SUBSTRING(StartAndEndDate, LEN(StartAndEndDate) - 23, 10) as StartDate`

Comment: Parsing the string like this will hurt performance, but if the database isn't that busy and it isn't being done every couple of minutes, it is probably still a reasonable approach. The preferred solution would be to pre-process the data before it gets to the database, but that may be more trouble than it is worth.

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Dates]
    (
      [ID] [INT] IDENTITY(1, 1)
                 NOT NULL ,
      [StartAndEndDate] [NVARCHAR](100) NOT NULL 
    ); 


INSERT  INTO [dbo].[Dates]
        ( StartAndEndDate )
VALUES  ( 'JayZ -  (08/21/2016 - 08/22/2016)' ),
        ( 'JohnSmith -  (09/11/2016 - 09/20/2016)' ),
        ( 'Rick from NY -  (08/21/2016 - 08/22/2016)' );

WITH    CTE
          AS ( SELECT   Name = SUBSTRING(StartAndEndDate, 0,
                                         CHARINDEX('-', StartAndEndDate)) ,
                        StartAndEndDate = SUBSTRING(StartAndEndDate,
                                                    CHARINDEX('(',
                                                              StartAndEndDate)
                                                    + 1,
                                                    CHARINDEX(')',
                                                              StartAndEndDate)
                                                    - CHARINDEX('(',
                                                              StartAndEndDate)
                                                    - 1)
               FROM     dbo.[Dates]
             )
    SELECT  Name ,
            StartDate = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(StartAndEndDate, 0,
                                              LEN(StartAndEndDate)
                                              - CHARINDEX('-', StartAndEndDate)))) ,
            EndDate = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(StartAndEndDate,
                                            CHARINDEX('-', StartAndEndDate)
                                            + 1,
                                            LEN(StartAndEndDate)
                                            - CHARINDEX('-', StartAndEndDate)
                                            + 1)))
    FROM    CTE;
```

Result:

[image]